# Random forest model fitting

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using miniconda, python 3.6 in machine learning analytics but when i try to fit the model in random forest algorithm with `fit` as `rf_model.fit(x=data.f(features),y=["xxx"])`,

an error occurs:

> fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Y'`

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
rf_model.fit(x=data.f(features),y=["xxx"])
```

to

```
rf_model.fit(X=data.f(features),y=["xxx"])
```

(that is, big `X` and small `y`). Or you can just omit them and write

```
rf_model.fit(data.f(features),["xxx"])
```

See below an example of the format, taken from [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#forest):

```
>>> from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
>>> X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
>>> Y = [0, 1]
>>> clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
>>> clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
rf_model.fit(x=data.f(features),y=["xxx"])
```

To :

```
rf_model.fit(data.f(features),["xxx"])
```